# Simple popup or dialog box in Google Apps Script

Tags: popup, google-apps-script, popupwindow

I'm looking for simple code that adds a popup in my Google Apps Script Ui that comes up when I hit a submit button. The popup box would display a message and have a button to close the popup.

I've looked all over the place - everything seems so complicated and does way more than I need it to do.

This is the current code I have for the submit button.

```
     function doGet() {
       var app = UiApp.createApplication();
       app.setTitle("My Logbook");

       var hPanel_01 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
       var vPanel_01 = app.createVerticalPanel();
       var vPanel_02 = app.createVerticalPanel();
       var vPanel_03 = app.createVerticalPanel();

       var submitButton = app.createButton("Submit");

       //Create click handler
       var clickHandler = app.createServerHandler("submitData");
       submitButton.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
       clickHandler.addCallbackElement(hPanel_01);


       ////Test PopUp Panel
       var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
       var app = UiApp.createApplication;
       var dialog = app.createDialogBox();
       var closeHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(dialog).setVisible(false);
       submitButton.addClickHandler(closeHandler);

       var button= app.createButton('Close').addClickHandler(closeHandler);

       dialog.add(button);
       app.add(dialog);
       //////



       return app;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using zIndex? It places the panel above all of your other panels...

```
var popupPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('popupPanel')
    .setVisible(false)      
    .setStyleAttribute('left', x)  
    .setStyleAttribute('top', y)        
    .setStyleAttribute('zIndex', '1')
    .setStyleAttribute('position', 'fixed');
```

x = panel position from the left portion of your app
y = panel position from the top portion of your app
zIndex = the 'layer' your panel will appear on. You can stack panels using '1', '2', '3' etc.
position = your panel will be in a fixed position denoted by (x,y)

Visibility is set to false until you click submit, then have a client handler for your submit button make the popupPanel visible. When you click the button on your popupPanel, have the client handler set visibility to false once again and it will disappear.

One more thing, I noticed you get the active app and then create a new app. You do not need to create a new app...just new panels inside your app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No prob...I use it frequently to have multiple layered panels in some apps. It can be quite effective.

Answer (score 8):

Since [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app) is depreciated, [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) should be used to create custom user interfaces.

To prompt simple popup to display a message, use `alert` method of [Ui class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

```
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
ui.alert('Hello world');
```

will prompt simple popup with hello world and an ok button.

To display customized html template in Dialog, use HTMLService to create template and then pass it to `showModalDialog` method of Ui Class

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<div>Hello world</div>").setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "My Dialog");
```

`HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile` allows you to display html that is in a separate file. see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/)

Comment: THAT is what I was looking for a simple single/two line code for a SIMPLE message box. What happened to JUST `alert("msg");` anyway? WHY the over complication GOOGLE?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **dialogbox** to popup.
Add a button to the dialog-box. Add a **client handler** that sets the dialog box invisible,once you click the button.

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication;
var dialog = app.createDialogBox();
var closeHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(dialog).setVisible(false);

var button= app.createButton('Close').addClickHandler(closeHandler);

dialog.add(button);
app.add(dialog);
```

This should help.

**EDIT**

Added "()" after .createClientHandler. That should remove issues related to  **TypeError: Cannot find function createDialogBox in object function createApplication() {/* */}**

Comment: If I already have var app = UiApp.createApplication; in my script do I add another for the dialogbox?

Comment: How do I connect this to my submit button so that it becomes visible when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: if u already have var app, then use var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); and for submit button, just add submitButton.addClickHandler(closeHandler);

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong- I'm getting error: TypeError: Cannot find function createDialogBox in object function createApplication() {/* */} .  I've updated my code above...  I've left out the code for adding the panels and submit button to the application just to keep it simplified here.

Comment: I donot know why do you want the two lines after '//Testpopup ....' comment? And also correct the line var closeHandler = app.createClientHandler.forTargets(dialog).setVisible(false); by adding () after .createClientHandler

Comment: I don't necessarily want the two lines... I just don't know if I need them. I changed the code so you could see what I have and perhaps guide me in how to change it to work with a popup. I fixed the .createClientHandler()

Comment: He is missing the ellipses after UiApp.createApplication

Comment: @balajiboss is missing the ellipses after UiApp.createApplication; It should read: var app = UiApp.createApplication();

As well, this solution works OK as long as you like the light blue border and drop shadow on the dialogbox. Unfortunately, you cannot style a dialog box. If you want to style your popup box, you will need to create a simplePanel, verticalPanel, flowPanel or the like and use the zIndex method.

Answer (score 0):

Popup - use something like this:

```
      var table = app.createFlexTable();
      table.setStyleAttribute("position", "absolute");
      table.setStyleAttribute("background", "white");
```

add items to the table and hide and show as needed.